# ethereumj.starter running locally but bestBlock always remains at 0

Tags: ethereumj

I ran the following commands to get `ethereumj.starter` code and run it.

```
%> git clone https://github.com/ether-camp/ethereumj.starter
%> cd ethereumj.starter
%> ./gradlew run
```

From the log file and console output, I could see that the node started up, connected to peers and was also syncing. However, in another terminal window, the output of the following command was always `0`, as shown below.

```
%> curl -w "\n" -X GET http://localhost:8080/bestBlock
0
```

This was despite the log file showing transactions being received, and also having logged messages like the following, with some high block number listed as `best block` ....

```
Peer V63: [ 267c54b3,    NODE_RETRIEVING, ping     95 ms, difficulty 270944163663211043882, best block 3723188 ]: (idle 3s of 20s) Geth/v1.6.0-stable-facc47cb/windows-amd64/go1.8.1    Nodes/sec: 3681.86, miss: 0.00
```

Am I missing something here? Shouldn't the best block number reported by the `curl` command be increasing with time as the local node gets sync'ed?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the ethereumj starter to work by editing the ethereumj.conf file. I found that using this file worked (after commenting out the private key):

https://gist.github.com/Glamdring/cc575d0998ecbf6c519a4d95ee5faaa3

Here is the config:

```
peer {
    # Network id (=1 real network)
    networkId = 3

    # Port on which ethereumj will listen
    # for incoming connections
    listen.port = 30304

    # Private key of the peer
    # The key is generated by default on the first run and stored in the database folder
    # If you have your own peer ID, specify its private key here
    #privateKey = 9feea28......

    # Test peers
    ip.list = [
        "94.242.229.4:40404",
        "94.242.229.203:30303",
        "128.199.55.137:30303",
        "52.169.94.142:30303"
    ]
}

sync.enabled = false

database {
    # place to save physical storage files
    # can be either absolute or relative path
    dir = database1
}

# Blockchain settings (constants and algorithms) which are
# not described in the genesis file (like MINIMUM_DIFFICULTY or Mining algorithm)
# The possible named presets are:
# - main : the main network (Frontier-Homestead-...)
# - ropsten: Ropsten test network
# - testnet: Ethercamp test network
# - olympic: pre-Frontier Olympic network
# For custom network settings please refer to 'blockchain.config.class'
blockchain.config.name = ropsten

# the folder resources/genesis
# contains several versions of
# genesis configuration according
# to the network the peer will run on
genesis = ropsten.json
```

It would be nice if EthereumJ Starter would update their config file to something that works.

Comment: yes, I've noticed there isn't much activity on their GitHub recently. I've had a pull request opened for 2 weeks.